# How do I extract fields with dates, that were year ago in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask SQLAlchemy database, here it is.

```
class Debt(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    amount = db.Column(db.Float)
    employee = db.Column(db.String(100))
```

What I need is to get a sum of `amount` fields for entries, where difference between `date` field and today's date is more or equals 1 year. I am trying to use create a `yearAgo` variable, that holds today's date, but year ago (e.g. if today is 05/18/2021, `yearAgo` would be equal to 05/18/2020) and filter all the entries, where `date` field is less or equal to the `yearAgo` variable.

`result = db.session.query(func.sum(Debt.amount)).filter(Debt.date <= yearAgo)`

But it doesn't work, apparently because the proper SQL query is not formed. When I print out `result` I get

```
SELECT sum(debt.amount) AS sum_1 
FROM debt 
WHERE date(debt.date) <= ?
```

I suppose, there must be something else instead of questionmark. How do I make it work?

Comment: It looks alright-- are you actually running the query e.g. `result = db.session.query(func.sum(Debt.amount)).filter(Debt.date <= yearAgo).scalar()` (or .`.all()`, `.first()`) ?

Comment: @Doobeh, now when I call `scalar()` I get `<bound method Query.scalar of <flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery object at 0x7f822663dca0>>`  in return, but don't get the actual sum. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @Doobeh and to whom it may concern, I've solved my problem. At first, it turned out that I've called `scalar` and not `scalar()` so I referred to method itself and not it's return. Secondly, I considered slicing time off my `DateTime` object `yearAgo` a good idea for some reason. Don't do this, otherwise you will get a type error, because "SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input" and somehow when you use `yearsAgo = yearsAgo.date` the final `yearsAgo` is not a `DateTime` object, but a `<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>`.

Comment: You made the same mistake when you did `yearsAgo = yearsAgo.date` as with `scalar` it should be `yearsAgo.date()`.  Glad you got it working!